# How to remove Github integration from the Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ios, git, github, visual-studio-code, carthage

I can't find the way to disable the github popup in the Visual Studio Code, when I'm using terminal build inside the VSCode.

I've already disabled "Git Authentication" for Github in the settings, yet the popup is still there after using `carthage bootstrap --platform ios` (for iOS development).

In the generic "Terminal.app" session the same command works well and does not ask for the credentials (I've got an ssh setup that works well).

Happens on:

- macOS 11.2.1 (20D74)
- VSCode Version: 1.53.2
- Carthage version: 0.37.0.
- git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

[image: Github popup]

Any ideas on how to disable it (or maybe even uninstall the github extension)?

Comment: who is doing the `git push` or `git pull`? Does the Terminal have access to your global git credentials.

Comment: carthage command is using the git. Terminal inside the VSCode has access to global git. When I do `git clone git@github.com:xyz/abc.git` it works fine without the popup!